# Unity Newtonsoft is started to not working on iPhone and iPad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I was using using Newtonsoft.Json; to convert json to Objects in Unity like this:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<string>>(jsonData);
```

I don't know what I've changed in project but it stopped to work properly on iPad and iPhone devices. It currently works well on macOS while I am running the project on Unity. Where should I look? What can I do? Any suggesstions?

I tried to do this convertion in also JsonUtility but it did not work in macOS too.

Class Example:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[Serializable]
public class Response<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public Response()
    { }
    
    public Response(bool status, T data)
    {
        Status = status;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

and the example json is:

{"status":true,"data":"someStringValue"}

Comment: What exactly does `not working` mean? And not sure but you might need to use the [`JsonConstructor`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) attribute?

Comment: try to use [Preserve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Scripting.PreserveAttribute.html) attribute